# NAT: Exposing SQL Server 2008 Express to the internet

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008, nat

I have a Windows Server 2003 SP2 machine with SQL Server 2008 Express installed. I have my network configured with a NAT.

Internal clients can access the instance of SQL Server without a problem. I would like to enable SQL Server to be accessible from anywhere on the the internet.

I am not sure how to allow my NAT firewall to allow that. I tried adding the port 1443 to it but I still can't access it from a remote machine.

How can you make a given SQL Server available to the WAN?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what brand/type your NAT/Firewall is you may look at [Port Forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Forwarding)

This allows the public address of your NAT to recieve traffic to a specified port and then direct it through the NAT to the specific machine.